# Should this be called a mutex?

Tags: c++, mutex

I have objects that can be opened in different modes, among which read and write.
If you opened it read you can still call

```
object->upgradeOpen();
```

It is common practice in our code to call

```
object->downgradeOpen();
```

When you are done writing.
I usually find it easier to use the concept of a mutex that I learned in c++ essentials where you let this upgradeOpen and downgradeOpen be done in the constructor and destructor of this mutex object.

```
class ObjectMutex{
public:
    ObjectMutex(const Object& o)
      : m_o(o)
    {
        m_o.upgradeOpen();
    }

    ~ObjectMutex(){
        m_o.downgradeOpen();
    }
private:
    Object m_o;
};
```

Only problem is, it doesn't really lock the object to make it thread safe, so I don't think it really is a mutex.
Is there another accepted name to call this construction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principle which is implemented in this class is called RAII (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

In general such objects can be called "RAII object".

For the name in code you can use `ScopedSomething`. In this particular case, for example, `ScopedObjectUpgrader` or another meaningful name of action which is done for the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me more like an [upgradable mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.sharable_upgradable_mutexes)

Take a look at RAII wrappers for upgradable mutexes [How to unlock boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock (made from boost::shared_mutex)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704870/how-to-unlock-boostupgrade-to-unique-lock-made-from-boostshared-mutex) to get a better idea of how to write one yourself.

For example you probably want to write two separate RAII wrappers

```
class OpenLock {
public: 
    OpenLock(Object& o_in) : o{o_in} {
        this->o.open();
    }
    ~OpenLock() {
        this->o.close();
    }
private:
    Object& o;
};

class UpgradeOpenLock {
public:
    UpgradeOpenLock(Object& o_in) : o{o_in} {
        this->o->upgradeOpen();
    }
    ~UpgradeOpenLock() {
        this->o->downgradeOpen();
    }
private:
    Object& o;
};
```

and then use it like this

```
{
    OpenLock open_lck(o);
    // freely read
    {
        UpgradeOpenLock upgrade_lck(o);
        // freely read or write
    }
    // freely read again
}
```

Comment: The principle sounds right but can I use it to implement my code?

Comment: @turoni Yep!  Take a look at the linked question for an example of how to build an RAII wrapper around upgradable mutexes

Comment: Could you maybe add a code example because I don't see how using this would be easier than using the simple class I wrote.

Comment: I think you meant to store object by reference, not by value in the classes?

Comment: @downvoter why was my answer downvoted?  Please consider leaving a comment to explain how I can improve my answer

Comment: @turoni did this answer your question?

Comment: @Curious sorry for the delay I was in a meeting. Thank you for the effort but I don't feel like your answer offers an improvement to my code. UpgradeOpenLock seems the same as my provided code and OpenLock is not something I asked for and also not something I need.
I am sorry to hear you were downvoted, I really apreciated the effort you put into this but k.v. 's answer just answers my original question better.